# byobu won't start automatically

Tags: byobu

I am using the lovely byobu for a while, but I know it's "wrong" to lunch it inside .zshrc, since I get the message

> "sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force"

I tried the classical way, that is, pressing F9 and I toggled on login startup, which dows not seems to work.

Do you know how to fix it?

What I need to know to debug this problem? I have the feeling I am missing something in the architecture of a shell.

Answer (score 0):

`.zshrc` is executed every time a new zsh instance is created. `.profile` is running on each login. You should start your byobu in the `.profile`, not in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

modify your byobu config in .bashrc as follow:

```
if [ -n "$BASH" ] && [ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -z "$STARTED_BY_BYOBU" ] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    byobu
fi
```

`-n` checks if the string inside double quotes is not empty, `-z` checks if string is empty, we're basically verifying if this is an interactive shell (with $BASH and $PS1 (env)ironment variables) and there's no previous byobu instances has existed (with the other 2 env)

p.s. i tried putting the above script inside my .bash_profile and rebooted, didn't work